# iOS UIView becomes slower after suspend/resume

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage, core-graphics

I noticed a strange thing: UIView becomes twice slower in terms of performing `UIImage.drawAt` after suspend/resume. I see 2x drop in FPS both on simulator and devices on iOS 9-13 after pressing Home and returning to app. Its ability in terms of `String.drawAt` or filling rectangles stays the same (it also makes less likely some mistake of mine in restarting after resume).

Can anyone explain why and how it can be fixed? Recreating a view after resume fixes the problem, but I'd rather used an existing instance.

Below is a short example. You need only some image added into assets (my was 112x145 PNG with transparency). If your image is so small that example app shows 60 FPS, increase `max` parameter in the last method.

**EDIT** Be sure to include your image to all x1, x2, x3, so that a native resolution is loaded. Otherwise upscaling will be the slowest operation, not drawing.

```
//  AppDelegate.swift

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder,UIApplicationDelegate
{
  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)->Bool
  {
    self.window=UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let testViewController=TestViewController()
    window!.rootViewController=testViewController
    Runner._instance.testViewController=testViewController
    return true
  }

  func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)
  {
    Runner._instance.stop()
  }

  func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication)
  {
    Runner._instance.start()
  }

  func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication)
  {
    Runner._instance.stop()
  }
}

class Runner: NSObject
{
  static let _instance=Runner()
  var testViewController: TestViewController!
  var displayLink: CADisplayLink!
  var fps=0
  var lastFpsCounterTime=Date().timeIntervalSince1970
  var fpsCounter=0

  func start()
  {
    if displayLink == nil
    {
      displayLink=CADisplayLink(target: self,selector: #selector(Runner.run))
      displayLink.add(to: RunLoop.main,forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)
    }
  }

  func stop()
  {
    displayLink?.invalidate()
    displayLink=nil
  }

  @objc func run()
  {
    if lastFpsCounterTime+1<Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    {
      fps=fpsCounter
      lastFpsCounterTime=Date().timeIntervalSince1970
      fpsCounter=0
    }
    fpsCounter+=1
    testViewController.view.setNeedsDisplay()
  }
}

class TestViewController: UIViewController
{
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
  {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    loadView()
  }

  override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)
  {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil,bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    loadView()
  }

  override func loadView()
  {
    view=TestView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
  }
}

class TestView: UIView
{
  let image=UIImage(named: "card")!

  required init?(coder: NSCoder)
  {
    super.init(coder: coder)
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect)
  {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    isOpaque=true
  }

  override func draw(_ _rect: CGRect)
  {
    let context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.setFillColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    context.fill(bounds)
    let max=50  //Choose max high enough to get less than 60 FPS
    let time=Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    for i in 1...max
    {
      //image.draw(at: ) is affected by suspend/resume, but "String".draw(at: ) is not 
      image.draw(at: CGPoint(x: (image.size.width+bounds.width)*CGFloat(time.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: Double(1+i))/Double(1+i))-image.size.width,y: bounds.height*CGFloat(i)/CGFloat(max)))
    }
    let font=UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 15)!
    let textFontAttributes=[NSAttributedString.Key.font: font,
     NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1),
     NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle]
    "FPS: \(Runner._instance.fps)".draw(at: CGPoint(x: 2,y: 30),withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
  }
}
```

Comment: `NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: NSMutableParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle` is very weird.

Comment: The way to measure speed is Instruments.